# If $X_n$ is binomial(n,p), then for any $b>0, P(X_n\le b)\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: probability

If $X_n$ is binomial(n,p), then for any $b>0, P(X_n\le b)\rightarrow 0$.

I used Hoeffding's inequality here:

Since $EX_n=np$ and $X_n\in \{0,1\}\forall n\ge 1$, then

$$\displaystyle P(\bar{X}_n \ge b+np)\le 2\exp\left( -\frac{2nb^2}{1^2}\right) \rightarrow 0$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

But I'm not sure how to show that $P(X_n\le b)\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binomial Random Variable $X_n$ is sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables of paramter $p$:
$$
X_n=Y_1+...+Y_n
$$
For enough large $n$, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that:
$$
\Pr(X_n \leq {b})=\Pr(\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n}\leq \frac{b}{n})\leq \Pr(\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n}\leq p- \epsilon) (*)
$$
By weak law of large numbers,you have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr(\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n}>p-\epsilon)=1
$$ 
and so the limit on the right hand side of $(*)$ goes to zero.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have two questions:
1. How the inequality part come about in terms of $\frac{b}{n}$ and $p-\epsilon$ being related? If $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N s.t. \mid \frac{b}{N}-1\mid < \epsilon$, then we have $p-\epsilon < \frac{b}{N}$

2. WLLN says $P\left(\frac{Y_1+...+Y_n}{n}\le p+\epsilon \right)\rightarrow 1$ but in (*) we have $p-\epsilon$, why does the right hand side go to 0?

Comment: If you choose $n>\frac{b}{p-\epsilon}$ for$p>\epsilon$, then the inequality follows. Secondly, the WLLN says $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr(|\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n}-p|<\epsilon)=1$. From which you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr(\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n}>p-\epsilon)=1$